# How to change the block devices under /dev/block or /dev?

Tags: linux-kernel, block-device

Block devices in different versions of the kernel,some under /dev ,others under /dev/block,how to change them under /dev or /dev/block? eg. /dev/loop0 and /dev/block/loop0.

[image: Screenshot :]

Comment: /dev/block contains symbolic links of the form _major:minor_ linking to the block devices in /dev. They are created by UDEV.

Comment: If I want change all block devices from /dev to /dev/block,rather than use a symbolic links。How to change them? eg. I want to use /dev/block/loop0,not /dev/loop0。

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not add pictures of text. Instead copy&paste the text directly into the question.